# Thread not wanting to work

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, paint

If so someone could explain how to get this to paint and why it isn't painting  that would be awesome!!!

```
public class Main extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

        System.out.println("g");
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(50, 50, 200, 200);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Physics!");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Main physics = new Main();
        Thread t = new Thread(physics);
        t.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: It has a mind of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never add `physics` to the `JFrame`

```
Main physics = new Main();
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Physics!");
frame.add(physics);
```

---

**Side Note**

- When painting on `JPanel` override `getPreferredSize()` so the panel has a preferred size, then you can just `pack()` the frame, as you *should* be doing, instead of setting it's size

  ```
  @Override
  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(500, 500);
  }
  ...
  frame.pack();
  // frame.setSize(500, 500);
  ```
- Also, `paintComponent` should be `protected` not `public`
- Also see [**Initial Threads**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for running Swing apps on the Event Dispatch Thread

Comment: When doing the dimension thing it just puts the little bitty frame?

Comment: You need to also `pack()` your frame, _before_ you `setVisible()` and _after_ you `add(physics)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the JPanel to the JFrame:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Physics!");
    Main physics = new Main();
    Thread t = new Thread(physics);
    t.start();
    frame.setContentPane(physics); // Add it like this
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting t.join() in the main method after t.start() .. Your main method should wait for the thread to finish.